# bokeh plottng figure shows unequal spacing in y axis labels/ticks

Tags: python, bokeh

Am trying to plot a bokheh.plotting figure for my data that has categorical values.
The plot does appear to come alright, however the y-axes is seen randomly spaced. Also some y-ticks are coming in bold ?
I am attaching the figure and the code for your reference:

```
 from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
 output_file("categorical.html")

 p = figure(y_range = y, plot_width=800, plot_height=800)

 p.circle(x, y, size=sizes*3, fill_color = 'white', line_color="green", 
        line_width=2, legend = "abc")
 p.circle(x_1, y_1, size = sizes_1**2, fill_color = 
        'white',line_color="yellow", line_width=2,legend = "def")
 p.circle(x_2, y_2, size = sizes_2**2, fill_color = 'white', 
        line_color="blue", line_width=2,legend = "pqr")
 p.circle(x_3, y_3, size = sizes_3**2, fill_color = 'white', 
        line_color="black", line_width=2,legend = "xyz")
 p.circle(x_4, y_4, size = sizes_4**2, fill_color = 
        'white',line_color="red", line_width=2,legend = "fgh")
 p.circle(x_5, y_5, size = sizes_5**2, fill_color = 
          'white',line_color="brown", line_width=2,legend = "tyu")
 p.circle(x_6, y_6, size = sizes_6**2, fill_color = 
      'white',line_color="violet", line_width=2,legend = "qwe")

show(p)
```

Small sample snippets of my x,y:

```
  x = abcd[abcd['PRODUCT'] == 'STRUCTURED']['RI'].tolist()
  y = abcd[abcd['PRODUCT'] == 'STRUCTURED']
                                 ['CODE'].tolist()
   sizes = abcd[abcd['PRODUCT'] == 'STRUCTURED']
                                   ['logabs'].values
```

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly assist on this strange plotting output

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the way `p=figure(y_range = y)` was defined.

y_range should be unique list.

So

```
y_list =  pd.unique(abcd['CCY_CODE']).tolist()
Then p = figure(y_range = y_list , plot_width=1010, plot_height=800)
```

This helped.